# Restarting rails server, detached rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you restart the rails server?
I started it with

```
rails server -d
```

So the server is detached

The only way i know is to do
ps aux | grep rails
and kill -9
on the process #
But is it good to kill processes like this?

Is there any command in rails that is supposed to be used for stopping or restarting the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it in development? Are you using Thin, mod_rails, Unicorn or WEBRick?
If it's in dev, there shouldn't be any issues with just killing the process, _but_, first try sending a SIGTERM, which is basically what happens when you have the server without -d and you just CTRL+C to stop it, to send the SIGTERM just do kill pid (without the -9) and wait for a few secs to see if the signal was sent, if it doesn't kill the process, just kill -9 it and everything will be alright.

Answer (score 1):

Killing the detached server should have no negative consequences (given that there is nobody trying to reach the server). If there is still data that was not persisted however (e.g. from Active Directory caches) you would lose that, of course.
If you encounter that problem more often, you may want to think about creating a rake task that will stop the server for you.
As an alternative to

```
ps aux | grep ...
```

you could also use

```
lsof -i :[port]
```

where [port] is the port on which the server is running (default: 3000)